# swift custom context menu previewprovider can not click any view inside(using tapgesture)

Tags: swift, contextmenu, customization, uitapgesturerecognizer

im working with reaction like message, here is what i did (using customProvider from contextMenu)

below is the code when i added emoji action to customProvider controller

```
private func addReactionList(_ items : [Reaction]) -> UIView{
        let reactionView = UIView()
      
        
        var arrangedSubviews: [UIView] = []
        
        for reaction in items {
            let imgView = UIImageView(image: AppUtils.reactionToImage(reaction: reaction))
            imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: iconHeight, height: iconHeight)
            imgView.layer.cornerRadius = (imgView.frame.height) / 2
            imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            imgView.layer.borderWidth = 0
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imgView.restorationIdentifier = reaction.Type
            
            
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture(_:)))
            tapGesture.delegate = self
            tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
            tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            
            arrangedSubviews.append(imgView)
        }
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrangedSubviews)
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = padding
        stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding)
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        
        let width = (CGFloat(items.count) * iconHeight) + (CGFloat(items.count+1) * padding)
        reactionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: iconHeight + 2 * padding)
        reactionView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        reactionView.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.frame = reactionView.frame
        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        reactionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        return reactionView
    }
```

then i added this to custom provider vc:

```
let actionsReacts = addReactionList(likeReactions)
        let emojiReacts = addReactionList(emojiReactions)
        if let snap = customView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) as UIView?{
            view.addSubview(snap)
            view.addSubview(actionsReacts)
            view.addSubview(emojiReacts)
            
            let maxWidth = snap.frame.size.width >= actionsReacts.frame.size.width ? snap.frame.size.width : actionsReacts.frame.size.width
            
            var currentSnapFrame = snap.frame
            currentSnapFrame = CGRect(Int((maxWidth - snap.frame.size.width)) / 2, 0 , Int(snap.frame.size.width), Int(snap.frame.size.height))
            snap.frame = currentSnapFrame
            
            var currentActionsReactFrame = actionsReacts.frame
            currentActionsReactFrame = CGRect(0, Int(snap.frame.size.height), Int(actionsReacts.frame.size.width), Int(actionsReacts.frame.size.height))
            actionsReacts.frame = currentActionsReactFrame
            
            var currentEmojiReactFrame = actionsReacts.frame
            currentEmojiReactFrame = CGRect(0, Int(snap.frame.size.height) + Int(emojiReacts.frame.size.height), Int(emojiReacts.frame.size.width), Int(emojiReacts.frame.size.height))
            emojiReacts.frame = currentEmojiReactFrame
            
            
            preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: snap.frame.size.height + actionsReacts.frame.size.height + emojiReacts.frame.size.height)
        }
```

But the gesture can not fire, i tried to change img to button, but still not get click

```
@objc func handleTapGesture(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let tappedImage = sender.view as! UIImageView
        let reactionType = tappedImage.restorationIdentifier ?? ""
        onSelectedReaction?(reactionType)
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

i do not know why i can not click any where, even i tried to add gesture click to viewcontroller view. Can anyone explain it? Thanks in advance

Comment: im using new VC with tranparent + blur background with hero animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed to present new VC with hero animation, so bored, but it is my best choice for now

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reconstruct your demo app from what you have provided, but it is still not clear to me what your code is or how it behaves.

One thing I note that you are creating `n` gesture-recognizers and hooking each to an imageview.
Try instead using 1 gesture recognizer. Hook it to your parent view, and on tap-event, get the subview which is being hit.

Some code:

```
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onViewTap))
 parentView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

```
@objc func onViewTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = sender.location(in: containerView)
    if let hitSubview = parentView.hitTest(point, with: nil) {
 // check which subview (imageView) is being hit by checking its tag or similar
}
```

Comment: u got my 100 points, even that not help when debug in view hierarchy, i found my previewProvider  is below 1 scrollView that designed by Apple to handle panGesture and tapGesture.

Comment: if you using iPhone, u can see the reaction of Message app, that is what i want to say